# C# Microsoft.Search.Interop cannot be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, search, dll

I've developed a software that uses `microsoft.search.interop.dll` as referenced libraries.
When I compile with a debug mode, my app works correctly, but when I try to compile in release mode, I get this error:

> Microsoft.Search.Interop cannot be found.

I've downloaded code sample from http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/windowssearch (DSearch project).

How can I solve my problem?

Solution found (run the following on one line):

```
set MSSdk=c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1 
"%MSSdk%\Bin\tlbimp.exe" "%MSSdk%\Lib\SearchAPI.tlb" /namespace:Microsoft.Search.Interop /out:Microsoft.Search.Interop.dll /silent
```

Comment: I sometimes have that problem too with _.dll_. Have you tried removing the reference from your solution, saving the solution, closing it, reopening it then re-adding your _.dll_?

Comment: I've found a solution. Now I try with this workaround: set MSSdk=c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1

"%MSSdk%\Bin\tlbimp.exe" "%MSSdk%\Lib\SearchAPI.tlb" /namespace:Microsoft.Search.Interop /out:Microsoft.Search.Interop.dll /silent

Comment: That's good you came to give feed back on your problem. You should create a new answer with the solution and set it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

I used the author's proposed solution and it worked for me in Visual Studio 2012 on the DSearch.zip MSDN example.  To implement the solution, after I imported the project, I went to *Project* -> *{project-name} properties*. From there, go to *build events*.  Syntax for the author's proposed code did not work initially for me, but changing as follows did:

```
set MSSdk="c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1"
%MSSdk%\Bin\tlbimp.exe %MSSdk%\Lib\SearchAPI.tlb /namespace:Microsoft.Search.Interop /out:Microsoft.Search.Interop.dll /silent
```

You can confirm this works by running the command in your windows cmd prompt also. (read:"run cmd as administrator"; no message response==it worked)

[The solution is also voted on/accepted at social.MSDN.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssearch/thread/0a130e9d-4710-4a72-bf9e-272a3f0128d6/)

Answer (score 0):

It's may be that the dll is not present or its may be caching issue with Visual Studio. Please try the steps below. It works for me.

1. Download Windows Search 3.x SDK from [**this Link**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7388) and extract it.
2. You will find the microsoft.search.interop.dll inside folder name Managed.
3. Remove the existing reference of microsoft.search.interop.dll from your project.
4. Then Clean the solution.
5. Close your project and close Visual Studio.
6. Reopen the project and add a new reference to the microsoft.search.interop.dll present inside folder name Managed.
7. Now compile your project
8. Now run the following command

   set MSSdk=c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1 
   "%MSSdk%\Bin\tlbimp.exe" "%MSSdk%\Lib\SearchAPI.tlb" /namespace:Microsoft.Search.Interop /out:Microsoft.Search.Interop.dll /silen

Comment: We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found.

Comment: @eriksv88 The Windows Search 3.x SDK can be found on archive.org [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160528143742if_/https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/f/0/1f03e69f-8df9-4c9c-a2b5-184800ba8a3e/Windows%20Search%203x%20SDK.exe) (the url must copied and paste into new tab)

Answer (score 0):

I have been seeing this a lot, so I thought I might clarify something..

Those commands belong in the pre-build steps of a project that references the Microsoft.Search.Interop assembly. Ideally, that dll would be generated in the project bin folder, by adding the following to the "Pre-build event command line" in the "Build Events" section:

```
set MSSdk=c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1

"%MSSdk%\Bin\tlbimp.exe" "%MSSdk%\Lib\SearchAPI.tlb" /namespace:Microsoft.Search.Interop /out:Microsoft.Search.Interop.dll /silent
```

Note: You would not want to use the /silent switch on the command line and the path will differ on 64 bit machines or depending on the version of the SDK you have, so mine was as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A
```